# How to capture mouse event in MAC OS with c++

Tags: c++, macos

i want to capture mouse right and left click in Mac os and use below code:

---

```
CGEventRef event = CGEventCreate(NULL);
CGEventType eventType = CGEventGetType(event);
```

---

```
cout << "mouse event type is : " << eventType << endl;
```

---

i use this code to see eventType that for example must be kCGEventLeftMouseDown or an integer value that show Event Types, but this code dont capture mouse event and return 0

Comment: please rewrite the question title and the body too to make it easier to get what you want :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

how is this supposed to do ANYTHING :D you need to capture existing events ... you just call a helper and make a new event ... BUT it's quite straightforward.

look into `CGEventTap` that does what you want.

*Event taps work system wide given the OS has accessibility enabled!*

---

some code:

```
//called for each event
static CGEventRef myCGEventCallback(CGEventTapProxy proxy, 
                                        CGEventType t,
                                        CGEventRef event,
                                        void *refcon);

- (void)threaded_listenForDrags {
    if (!_eventTap)
    {
        int eventMask = CGEventMaskBit(kCGEventLeftMouseDown)
        | CGEventMaskBit(kCGEventLeftMouseUp) 
        | CGEventMaskBit(kCGEventLeftMouseDragged)
        | CGEventMaskBit(kCGEventRightMouseDragged)
        | CGEventMaskBit(kCGEventOtherMouseDragged);

        _eventTap = CGEventTapCreate(kCGHIDEventTap,
                                    kCGHeadInsertEventTap,
                                    kCGEventTapOptionListenOnly, 
                                    eventMask, 
                                    myCGEventCallback,
                                    (__bridge void*)self);
        if (!_eventTap)
        {
            DDLogError(@"%@ no tap; universal access?", NSStringFromSelector(_cmd));
            return;
        }
        CFRunLoopSourceRef runLoopSource = CFMachPortCreateRunLoopSource(NULL,
                                                                         _eventTap, 0);
        CFRunLoopAddSource(CFRunLoopGetCurrent(), runLoopSource, 
                           kCFRunLoopCommonModes);

        CFRelease(runLoopSource);       
    }
    CGEventTapEnable(_eventTap, true);

    CFRunLoopRun();
}

- (void)threaded_endListenForDrags {
    CFMachPortRef et = _eventTap;

    CGEventTapEnable(_eventTap, false);
    _eventTap = nil;

    dispatch_sync(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        if(_enabled) {
            _enabled = NO;
            [self setEnabled:YES];
        }
    }); 

    CFRunLoopStop(CFRunLoopGetCurrent());
    CFRelease(et);
}
```